# Disable calendar event moving - Vaadin

Tags: java, calendar, vaadin

I want to disable moving events from Vaadin Calendar

> All of these handlers are automatically set when creating a new Calendar. If you wish to disable some of the default functionality, you can simply set the corresponding handler to null. This will prevent the functionality from ever appearing on the user interface. For example, if you set the EventMoveHandler to null, the user will be unable to move events in the browser. --> [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/calendar.customizing.html)

I tried:

```
calendar.setHandler(null);

calendar.setHandler((EventMoveHandler) null);
calendar.setHandler((BaseEventMoveHandler) null);

EventMoveHandler handler = null;
calendar.setHandler(handler);

BaseEventMoveHandler baseHandler = null;
calendar.setHandler(baseHandler );
```

But nothing is working. Any suggestion....?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really works for me with Vaadin 7.4.5:

```
calendar.setHandler((EventMoveHandler)null);
calendar.setHandler((EventResizeHandler)null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable all handlers and make the calendar completely read-only, this worked for me.

```
calendar.setReadOnly(true);
```

EDIT1:
This approach however doesn't disable resize pointers for the events. Thus, the best solution I see is to use it together with [asmellado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3725227/asmellado%20asmellado)'s answer :

```
calendar.setReadOnly(true);
calendar.setHandler((EventMoveHandler)null);
calendar.setHandler((EventResizeHandler)null);
```

Also, if I did not use the setReadOnly method, I was running in some strage client-side exceptions when I tried to move the event.